Detection of trace chemicals - textbook
I'm trying to do a literature review of all the methods that are there to detect specific organic molecules that are there at a 0.1-5% concentration in a mix of vapours with other organic molecules and water. I have found gas chromatography, liquid chromatography (because there is also a liquid phase), mass spectrometry, IR spectrometry, SPR refractometry, electrochemical sensors (MOS, others) in the literature. But I'm after a good, comprehensive textbook that covers all the methods. Can you please suggest a few names?
